# How do I get Wordpress custom Post Type through ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wordpress, api

Our client has website in Wordpress and it contains custom post type (like post_type=recent-news). Now we need to fetch and show all those custom post types and its content in ASP.Net website.

We have tried "CookComputing.XmlRpcV2" but it doesn't support custom post type. We have checked JSON API but for that we need to deploy PHP code which we don't want to do. We have also checked Wordpress JSON for .Net (http://wordpressjsonnet.codeplex.com/) but its not officially released / not fully working.

Is there any another option (any free dll or Rest API plugin) to get custom post type for ASP.Net?

Comment: I had same sort of situation and we go with json api ta pass data,ya you have to write php code but just get content type data and set it in to json format..,that's it..,

Answer (score 0):

4 years late but might help someone else. Try [WordpressSharp](http://abrudtkuhl.github.io/WordPressSharp/)'s method:

```
WordPressService.GetPosts(WordPressSiteConfig.BlogId, WordPressSiteConfig.Username,
                WordPressSiteConfig.Password, new PostFilter() {  PostType="recent-news"});
```